# delayWhen vs delay difference in a specific use case

Tags: typescript, rxjs, pipe

Let's say I built a pipe that contains a `retryWhen` in the end to catch the errors. What's the difference between

```
retryWhen(err => {
        return err.pipe(
            tap(() => {console.log(`retrying...`)}),
            delayWhen(() => timer(2000))
        )
    })
```

and

```
retryWhen(err => {
        return err.pipe(
            tap(() => {console.log(`retrying...`)}),
            delay(2000)
        )
    })
```

besides the different usage of the two operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there's no difference between them, both return an Observable that emits after 2 seconds.
You might prefer `delay` as it's more explicit.